# How to run ruby script at system start in background

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, gnu-screen

I need always running Ruby script at ubuntu 12.04.
Now i connect to server at putty and type "ruby execute.rb", but with closing or disconnect console that will stop

If i add "ruby execute.rb" to my ~/.bash_profile - when i connect to server at putty, my window maintain this script and i can't type other commands

So, i want that script works always and starts if system reboot, and i can use any commands in terminal

Answer (score 0):

To run script at system start, you can put your command in `/etc/rc.local`

```
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
```

Comment: I add to rc.local : "cd /var/www/nw;screen -d -m ruby execute.rb"

But when i connect via putty and type "screen -r" - i see nothing screens

That command work correctly while in ~/.bashprofile, but i need run command at system start (not user connect)